# How to generate excel from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have this multi dimensional array that I want to write this array in  excel file and then email it as an attachment.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "77",
      "m_id": "86",
      "sub_id": null,
      "s_id": "130",
      "amt": "50.00",
      "credit_amount": "0.00",
      "amt_stamp": "-40.00",
      "t_type": "Stock",
      "t_type_sub": "Cash",
      "t_mode": "Cr",
      "t_desc": "",
      "picture": null,
      "short_url": null,
      "send_sms": "0",
      "post_time": "2017-09-19 15:51:56",
      "bank": null,
      "credit": null,
      "sub_account": null,
      "expense": null,
      "expense_account": null
    },
    {
      "id": "68",
      "m_id": "86",
      "sub_id": null,
      "s_id": "130",
      "amt": "100.00",
      "credit_amount": "-1000.00",
      "amt_stamp": "10.00",
      "t_type": "Stock",
      "t_type_sub": "Cash",
      "t_mode": "Cr",
      "t_desc": "checking SMS",
      "picture": null,
      "short_url": null,
      "send_sms": "1",
      "post_time": "2017-08-30 15:45:18",
      "bank": null,
      "credit": null,
      "sub_account": null,
      "expense": null,
      "expense_account": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to write this array in excel sheet and, after writing the array, then email it as an attachment.
I want output like this in excel format:

```
id   m_id   amt
21   2      4000
22   5      5000
```

Comment: So what do you have so far, where are you stuck specifically?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going - easiest is probably to use .csv file type. If you want to switch the rows/columns lay-out you can 'transpose' the data in excel (copy/paste options - transpose)

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('./json_src.json');
$sourcedata = json_decode($json, true);
$handle = fopen("output.csv",'w+b') or die("problem opening csv file");

foreach($sourcedata as $key => $value)
{
        foreach($value as $key => $value)
        {           
            foreach($value as $key => $value)
            {
            // set the fields you'd like to copy to .csv
            if($key==='id' || $key === 'm_id' || $key === 'amt')
                {
                $csv[]= array($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }
}

foreach($csv as $key => $value)
{
fputcsv($handle, $value);
}
fclose($handle) or die("problem closing file");
?>
```